# How to send Push Notifications in Production?

Tags: php, ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have submitted an App to the App Store. I generated a Token with my Device and sent it with following PHP-Scritp:

```
$deviceToken = 'b6e03b75f73bb9133c34434a09390e29g12696e8f32b3d29d1dd97a7e0a9adbd';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'Passwort';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = $titel;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Zertifikate.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => '+1'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Nachricht wurde nicht zugestellt' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'PUSHH!!' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

It says that it is connected to APNS and the result is positive.
I don't know what I should do. I just use the same code in production like in development, but I am sending my data to the gateway.push.apple.com-Server.

Comment: And I am using a production certificate

Comment: Did the device receive the notification? It is not clear what your question is

Comment: No. This is the problem. APNS says that everything is fine and the notification were submitted, but I don't get any notifications.

Comment: Check the following: Is the device key correct? Is the production version of the application installed on that device? Has the production version of the application been run on that device (needed to actually register the device with APNS)? Are the device settings allowing push notifications for that app?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine, but it doen't show any notifications..